# Как по клику менять background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ссылка без фона по умолчанию. Нужно чтобы по клику фон становился #000 , и еще с последующим кликом убирался.

То есть, есть кнопка, которая открывает меню, при открытии у кнопки фон черный, при закрытии фон transparent. В js не силен, подскажите код пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

видимо как-то так

```js
$("a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).toggleClass('black');
});
```

```css
a {
   padding: 4px 20px;
}
.black {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж в метках jQuery... 

Тут логика простая:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.menu', function(){
  $('.menu').removeClass('active');//При клике сперва убираем класс со всех кнопок
  $(this).addClass('active');//Потом добавляем его на текущую кликнутую.
});
```

```css
.active {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="menu">1111</button>
<button class="menu">1111</button>
<button class="menu">1111</button>
```

Ровно то же самое на JS:

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');
for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  menu[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(let u = 0; u < menu.length; u++) {
      menu[u].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.active {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<button class="menu">1111</button>
<button class="menu">1111</button>
<button class="menu">1111</button>
```

Просто jQuery делает работу с циклами `for()` "за кадром".